# Do we need a Predicate Logic if the domain of discourse is finite, or would propostional logic be enough (in theory)?

Tags: logic

If the domain of dicourse is infinite we need some logic beyond propositional logic (PL), both to express and to model properly, because in PL you can only have formulas with a finite number of atomic sentences and every atomic sentence can just express one object/thought, so you could never "grasp" the infintely many objects by PL.

But if a domain of discourse is just finite (= finitely many objects in the set) then does it change it, could you do - in theory - everything with PL that you can do with Predicate Logic and vice versa? Or does Predicate Logic have a concept that you cannot translate into a PL formula, given a finite domain of discourse?

Comment: You would be able to express $\forall$ and $\exists$ only using logical connectives, so yes.

Comment: My idea too. But could I express with PL what a property is in FOL? Like for example take the domain = {1,2,3}. In FOL we can define the property P = "is a prime number" and we could state: "2 is a prime number" or "there exists something that is a prime number". How would u do that in PL to get the same result?

Comment: In that case you would have to use the quantifiers to state something like that (involving existence). Note that FOL allows us to work with quantifiers, that is the main difference from PL. If it was possible to handle that kind of expressions with PL, we wouldn’t have developed FOL, right?

Comment: So that means even if the domain of discourse in finite we still cannot express everything with PL what we can express with FOL? I am confused because you first comment suggests No, your second suggests Yes to this question.

Comment: You simply have to write: $P_1=$ "1 is a Prime" and so on. Thus, "there exists  a prime number" will be $P_1 \lor P_2 \lor P_3$

Comment: @Mauro: So you agree that as long as the domain is finite we can (although maybe in a crude/long-winded way in comparison to FOL) express anything with propositional logic what we can express with FOL?